# Fail to enable hive support in Spark submit (spark 3)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark in an integration test suite. It has to run locally and read/write files to local file-system. I also want to read/write these data as tables.

In the first step of the suite I write some hive tables in the db `feature_store` specifying
`spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/opt/spark/work-dir/warehouse`. The step completes correctly and I see the files in the folder I expect.

Afterwards I run a spark-submit step with (among others) these confs

```
--conf spark.sql.warehouse.dir=/opt/spark/work-dir/warehouse --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=hive
```

and when trying to read a table previously written I get

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchDatabaseException: Database 'feature_store' not found
```

However if I try to do exactly the same thing with exactly the same configs in a spark-shell I am able to read the data.

In the spark-submit I use the following code to get the spark-session

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.active();
```

I have also tried to use instead

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();
```

but I keep getting the same problem as above.

I have understood that the problem is related to the spark-submit not picking up hive as
catalog implementation. In fact I see that the class `spark.catalog` is not an instance of `HiveCatalogImpl` during the spark-submit (while it is when using spark-shell).